# How to add data subtext to the drop down, list from data base

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I have tried to build a drop down list with live search and i succeeded on that,And i also need a data sub-text to each item on the drop down list.

following code is my drop down list in html page

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model =>model.m_service_id,(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Prasadham,
                                     new
                                     {
                                         @class = "form-control selectpicker",
                                         @Value = @Model.code,                                       
                                         data_show_subtext = "true",
                                         data_live_search = "true"
                                     })
```

And my drop down populate function is below

```
public void PopulateGetService(object selectedState = null)
{
   var context = new Repository.alterationRepo();
   var result = context.GetPrasadham();
   ViewBag.Prasadham = new SelectList(result, "m_service_id", "service_name", selectedState);
}
```

So i need to display sub-text for each item in drop down option and also able to select the items when i type the sub-text in the live-search field.Hope u guys can answer my question.Thanks in advance. !

Comment: Thanks for the edits